# request.getRemoteHost() vs request.getHeader("HOST")

Tags: java, servlets

If I will execute `request.getRemoteHost()` and `request.getHeader("HOST")` on a Java server will these methods return the same values?
According to the documentation yes, but I will be happy for the confirmation:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteHost--

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `request.getRemoteHost()` : Returns the fully qualified name of the client that sent the request.

   So, If you access it via localhost you would get something like : `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`. If you access it via some other machine, it will return you the IP address of that machine.
2. `request.getHeader("HOST")` : Returns the value of the "Host" header in the request.

   So, If you are hitting an application url :  https://www.test.com, then request.getHeader("Host") would return you `www.test.com`

Comment: Will it return the same values?

Comment: Nope. I have added clarification in the answer.

Comment: Most important: request.getHeader("HOST") will also return port: e.g. localhost:80

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **NO**

The explanation is already there in the links you have provided.

Given below is the one for `request.getHeader("HOST")`:

> The Host request header specifies the host and port number of the
> server to which the request is being sent.

And the one below is about `request.getRemoteHost()`:

> Returns the fully qualified name of the client or the last proxy that
> sent the request. If the engine cannot or chooses not to resolve the
> hostname (to improve performance), this method returns the
> dotted-string form of the IP address.